# Get distinct levels of array field in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a mongo table that looks like this:

```
[
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5899d847c014c5287df3819a"), "id_pair" : [ 1, 0 ]},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5899d847c014c5287df3819b"), "id_pair" : [ 2, 0 ]
]
```

I'd like to query the table to get all distinct levels of the "id_pair" field, i.e.:

```
[
  [ 1, 0 ],
  [ 2, 0 ]
]
```

I tried using `db.woohoo.distinct('id_pair')`, but that returns `[0, 1, 2]`

Is there a way to return all levels of the "id_pair" factor? I'm using pymongo as my ORM, so any syntactic sugar it supports for this kind of query is a bonus.

Comment: The problem is that these are arrays values. If you would have pairs something like `[ [ 1, 0 ] ]` then `db.woohoo.distinct('id_pair')` would have work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run an aggregate operation that groups all the documents as a whole and then create the distinct set using **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet)** as follows:

**Mongo Shell**

```
db.woohoo.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "distinct_pairs": { "$addToSet": "$id_pair" }                
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "distinct_pairs" : [
        [ 1, 0 ],
        [ 2, 0 ]
    ]
}
```

**Example pymongo aggregate operation**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['somedb']
collection = db.woohoo

pipe = [{'$group': {'_id': 0, 'distinct_pairs': {'$addToSet': '$id_pair'}}}]

result = next(collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipe))['distinct_pairs']
print(result)
client.close()
```